# How to have function components behind React Router Dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to have my sidebar be a continual function component once you authorize. I do not want my sidebar to re-render every time it goes from say the `"/dashboard"`, to my `"/chat"` page. This is what I have right now.

```
<div className="flex flex-col ">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/sign-in' element={<Signin />} />
      <Route path='/sign-up' element={<Signup />} />
      <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/chat' element={<Chat />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='*' element={<p>There is nothing here: 404!</p>} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

However, when I cannot put my `<Sidebar />` component within the Routes. As you can see with my `Navbar`, is outside the routes, however, when I am under protected routes, I want my `Navbar` to go away and my sidebar to appear since the navbar is for the home pages. I could put it on each of the two pages manually, however I don't want it to re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use more layout routes (*like the `ProtectedRoute`*). Move the `Navbar` and (*presumably*) `Sidebar` components into layout routes to be conditionally rendered with the routes they wrap.

Example;

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavbarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const SidebarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Sidebar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

...

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<NavbarLayout />}>        
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path='/sign-in' element={<Signin />} />
      <Route path='/sign-up' element={<Signup />} />
      <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<SidebarLayout />}>
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/chat' element={<Chat />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<p>There is nothing here: 404!</p>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```